# Font files provided as exec files

Tags: fonts, file-format

I just received a zip with fonts from a client, but unfortunately they are all exec files (whatever that is) and i can't open them. What should I do to open them? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This could be a [self-extracting ZIP](http://kb.winzip.com/help/help_zip2exe.htm), or who knows what else. Be careful when running EXE files from unverified sources. Personally i wouldn't open EXE files received from anyone.

The most common file types for desktop fonts are [OTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) and [TTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType).

Answer (score 0):

These are not font files. There is no way to know what they are - but they could potentially be malicious software installation files. Don't do anything with them, do not try to open them or install them. Delete them. Tell the client you want the font files, and nothing else.